# How do I get the Organization name from Desire2Learn API?

Tags: desire2learn

How do I get the Organization name from the Desire2Learn API?

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute of the json returned for [org info](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-organization-info) has the name.